# Make thumbnail view with Firemonkey

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I'm tring to make a thumbnail viewer with Firemonkey (XE4), just like the thumbnail view mode of windows explorer (or vsIcon mode of TListView in VCL).

I tried ListBox by following the sample, however, it dosen't work. It can only simulate vsReport style.

I want to allow users to add picture files to this list and display all the thumbnail images one by one.

This is my first try with FM, I appreciate if anyone can help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I found if I set the itemwidth and itemheight, it may looks like vsIcon now.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you'll want TFlowLayout or TGridLayout: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/FireMonkey_Layouts_Strategies

Comment: TListbox can also achieve this. It has columns, and each listitem can be set to a fixed size.